# Multithreading with opencv and pthreads

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, opengl, pthreads

I wanted to get video frames from openCV and render it onto a graphics screen with openGL. I got it to work; however, the video drops frames consistently. I believe its because reading the frame and rendering is all on the same thread. Therefore, I implemented multithreading with pthreads but imshow is just a white screen. Also, it seems like the main thread does not run. I implemented a version with conditions and signals, and one with it. Any pointers to what I am doing wrong will be very helpful. Below is my code:

```
void *updateloop(void *arg)
{
    while(1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&frameLocker);
        while(my_queue.empty())
        {
            pthread_cond_wait(&condc, &frameLocker);
        }
        std::cout << "entering update loop" << std::endl;
        current_image = my_queue.front();
        my_queue.pop();
        /*
        if(!current_image.empty())
        {
            std::cout << "rendering to output window" << std::endl;
            cv::imshow("Output Window", current_image);
            cv::waitKey(30);
        }
        */
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&frameLocker);
    }

}

void *captureloop(void *arg)
{
    cv::Mat tempFrame;
    while(1)
    {
        std::cout << "entering capture loop" << std::endl;

        cap.read(tempFrame);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&frameLocker);
        my_queue.push(tempFrame);
        pthread_cond_signal(&condc);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&frameLocker);
    }
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cap.open(0);
    pthread_mutex_init(&frameLocker, NULL);
    pthread_t update, webcam;
    pthread_cond_init(&condc, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&condp, NULL);

    pthread_create(&update, NULL, updateloop, NULL);
    pthread_create(&webcam, NULL, captureloop, NULL);

    pthread_join(update, NULL);
    pthread_join(webcam, NULL);

    cv::Mat tempFrame;
    while (1)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&frameLocker);
        std::cout << "in the main thread" << std::endl;
        if(current_image.empty()){
            printf("recieved empty frame\n");
            continue;
        }
        if(!current_image.empty())
        {
            std::cout << "rendering to output window" << std::endl;
            cv::imshow("Output Window", current_image);
        }
        cv::waitKey(1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&frameLocker);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IMHO, you should 1) create threads 2) execute all command of a single library into a single thread, for example: I think `cap.open(0)` should be called from the same thread as the other OCV call's.

Comment: So that is what i did no? i put my cap.read() in one thread and my main thread only retrieves the frame and imshow() it? And when I place cap.open() inside one of the thread, the thread halts.

Comment: Keep all your OCV calls in the main thread so.